# Syntax error on android

Tags: android, syntax-error

i'm trying to develop an app and i can't launch it on the emulator. I have this block of code here

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



public abstract class Calculator extends Activity
  implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener
{
  private static final int SHOW_RECOMMEND_APP_MSG_ID = 65545;
  InputMethodManager adManager;

  ImageButton addButton;
  CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener boxListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
  {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton paramCompoundButton, boolean paramBoolean)
    {
      Calculator.this.setResult();
    }
  };
  View.OnClickListener buttonListener = new View.OnClickListener()
  {
    public void onClick(View paramView)
    {
      Object localObject;
      switch (paramView.getId())
      {
      case 2131165186:
        localObject = new Intent(Calculator.this, inputarea.class);
        ((Intent)localObject).putExtra("INT", false);
        Calculator.this.startActivityForResult((Intent)localObject, 152);
        break;
      case 2131165189:
        Calculator.this.percentSeekBar.setProgress(Calculator.this.percentValue - setting.getButton1(Calculator.this));
        break;
      case 2131165190:
        Calculator.this.percentSeekBar.setProgress(Calculator.this.percentValue - setting.getButton2(Calculator.this));
        break;
      case 2131165191:
        Calculator.this.percentSeekBar.setProgress(Calculator.this.percentValue + setting.getButton3(Calculator.this));
        break;
      case 2131165192:
        Calculator.this.percentSeekBar.setProgress(Calculator.this.percentValue + setting.getButton4(Calculator.this));
        break;
      case 2131165201:
        localObject = new Intent(Calculator.this, inputarea.class);
        ((Intent)localObject).putExtra("INT", false);
        Calculator.this.startActivityForResult((Intent)localObject, 153);
        break;
      case 2131165202:
        if (Calculator.this.totalValue != 0.0F)
        {
          Calculator.this.setResult();
          if (Utils.getSDKVersionNumber() <= 3)
            break;
          Calculator.this.setAnimation();
        }
        else
        {
          Calculator.this.shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Calculator.this, 2130968578);
          Calculator.this.totalValueButton.startAnimation(Calculator.this.shake);
          Toast.makeText(Calculator.this, 2131034139, 0).show();
        }
        break;
      case 2131165203:
        Calculator.this.resetView();
        break;
      case 2131165204:
        Calculator.this.listPrice.add(Float.valueOf(Calculator.this.resultValue));
        Calculator.this.listDiscount.add(Integer.valueOf(Calculator.this.percentValue));
        Calculator.this.listOriginPrice.add(Float.valueOf(Calculator.this.totalValue));
        Calculator.this.listSaved.add(Float.valueOf(Calculator.this.savedValue));
        localObject = Calculator.this;
        ((Calculator)localObject).totalPriceValue += Calculator.this.resultValue;
        localObject = Calculator.this;
        ((Calculator)localObject).totalSavedValue += Calculator.this.savedValue;
        Calculator.this.setTotalText();
        if (!Calculator.this.taxBox.isChecked())
          Calculator.this.listTax.add(Float.valueOf(Float.parseFloat("0")));
        else
          Calculator.this.listTax.add(Float.valueOf(setting.getConfigTax(Calculator.this)));
        Calculator.this.setListStatus();
        Calculator.this.priceList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
          private Builder setPositiveButton;

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paramAdapterView, View paramView, int paramInt, long paramLong)
          {
            Utils.l(paramInt + " was click");
            AlertDialog.Builder localBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Calculator.this);
            localBuilder.setMessage(2131034150);
            setPositiveButton = localBuilder.setPositiveButton(Calculator.this.getString(2131034151), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
              private int val$location;

            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt)
              {
                Calculator.this.removeItemFromList(this.val$location);
                Calculator.this.setTotalText();
                Calculator.this.setListStatus();
              }
            });
            localBuilder.setNegativeButton(Calculator.this.getString(2131034152), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt)
              {
              }
            });
            localBuilder.show();
          }
        });
      case 2131165187:
      case 2131165188:
      case 2131165193:
      case 2131165194:
      case 2131165195:
      case 2131165196:
      case 2131165197:
      case 2131165198:
      case 2131165199:
      case 2131165200:
      }
    }
  };
  Button calculateButton;
  Button clearButton;
  Context context;
  String ePercentString;
  Button firstButton;
  Button forthButton;
  private InfolifeEventListener infolifeEventListener = new InfolifeEventListener()
  {
    public void hasUpdate(JSONObject paramJSONObject)
    {
      Calculator.this.mHandler.obtainMessage(257).sendToTarget();
    }

    public void noUpdateNotification()
    {
      Calculator.this.mHandler.obtainMessage(259).sendToTarget();
    }

    public void onFetchedData(JSONObject paramJSONObject)
    {
      Message localMessage = Calculator.this.mHandler.obtainMessage(258);
      localMessage.obj = paramJSONObject;
      localMessage.sendToTarget();
    }



  private void checkUpdate()
  {
    boolean bool = true;
    if ((setting.getAutoUpdateStat(this)) && (Constants.market.shouldCheckUpdate()))
      bool = true;
    this.mChecker = new VersionChecker(this, this.infolifeEventListener, false);
    this.mChecker.checkUpdateinThread(bool, Constants.market.shouldShowRecommendApps());
    Utils.l("finish check :" + bool + "," + Constants.market.shouldShowRecommendApps());
  }

  private void removeItemFromList(int paramInt)
  {
    this.totalPriceValue = 0.0F;
    this.totalSavedValue = 0.0F;
    this.listPrice.remove(paramInt);
    this.listDiscount.remove(paramInt);
    this.listOriginPrice.remove(paramInt);
    this.listSaved.remove(paramInt);
    if (this.listPrice.size() == 0)
    {
      Utils.l("size=0");
      this.priceList.setVisibility(8);
      this.totalPriceLayout.setVisibility(8);
      this.totalSavedLayout.setVisibility(8);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= -1 + this.listPrice.size(); i++)
    {
      this.totalPriceValue += ((Float)this.listPrice.get(i)).floatValue();
      this.totalSavedValue += ((Float)this.listSaved.get(i)).floatValue();
    }
  }

  private void resetView()
  {
    this.percentSeekBar.setProgress(0);
    this.totalValueButton.setText(2131034123);
    this.totalValue = 0.0F;
    this.resultText.setText(2131034125);
    this.totalValueButton.requestFocus();
    this.totalPriceLayout.setVisibility(8);
    this.totalSavedLayout.setVisibility(8);
    this.priceList.setVisibility(8);
    this.listPrice.clear();
    this.listDiscount.clear();
    this.listOriginPrice.clear();
    this.listTax.clear();
    this.totalPriceValue = 0.0F;
    this.totalSavedValue = 0.0F;
    this.adapter = new priceListAdapter(this, this.listPrice, this.listOriginPrice, this.listDiscount, this.listTax);
    this.priceList.setAdapter(this.adapter);
  }

  private void setListStatus()
  {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)this.priceList.getLayoutParams();
    this.listHeight = (3 + Utils.dip2px(this));
    localLayoutParams.height = (this.listHeight * this.listOriginPrice.size());
    this.priceList.setLayoutParams(localLayoutParams);
    this.adapter = new priceListAdapter(this, this.listPrice, this.listOriginPrice, this.listDiscount, this.listTax);
    this.priceList.setAdapter(this.adapter);
  }

  private void setTotalText()
  {
    if (this.listSaved.size() != 0)
    {
      this.priceList.setVisibility(0);
      this.totalPriceLayout.setVisibility(0);
      this.totalSavedLayout.setVisibility(0);
    }
    this.totalPriceText.setText(Utils.currencyFormater.format(this.totalPriceValue));
    this.totalSavedText.setText(Utils.currencyFormater.format(this.totalSavedValue));
  }

  private void showDonateDialog()
  {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(17301576).setTitle(2131034158).setMessage(2131034159).setPositiveButton(2131034160, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt)
      {
        Utils.openDonateApp(Calculator.this);
      }
    }).setNegativeButton(2131034161, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt)
      {
        Utils.gotoMarket(Calculator.this);
      }
    }).show();
  }

  private void showFeaturedDialog()
  {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(2131034165).setMessage(2131034166).setPositiveButton(2131034156, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt)
      {
        Intent localIntent = new Intent(Calculator.this, FeaturedAppsActivity.class);
        Calculator.this.startActivity(localIntent);
      }
    }).setNegativeButton(2131034157, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt)
      {
      }
    }).show();
  }


  private void showRecommendDialog()
  {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(2130837510).setTitle(2131034154).setMessage(2131034155).setPositiveButton(2131034156, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt)
      {
        Utils.openRecommendApp(Calculator.this);
      }
    }).setNegativeButton(2131034157, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt)
      {
      }
    }).show();
  }

  private void showUpdateDialog(String paramString)
  {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(paramString).setPositiveButton(2131034148, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt)
      {
        Utils.gotoMarket(Calculator.this);
      }
    }).setNegativeButton(2131034149, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt)
      {
      }
    }).show();
  }

  public void cleanList()
  {
    this.listPrice.clear();
    this.listDiscount.clear();
    this.listOriginPrice.clear();
    this.listSaved.clear();
  }

  protected void onActivityResult(int paramInt1, int paramInt2, Intent paramIntent)
  {
    super.onActivityResult(paramInt1, paramInt2, paramIntent);
    if (paramIntent != null)
    {
      if ((paramInt1 == 152) && (paramInt2 == 100))
      {
        this.totalValue = Float.parseFloat(paramIntent.getStringExtra("value").toString());
        this.totalValueButton.setText(Utils.currencyFormater.format(this.totalValue));
        setResult();
      }
      if ((paramInt1 == 153) && (paramInt2 == 100))
      {
        this.taxValue = Float.parseFloat(paramIntent.getStringExtra("value").toString());
        this.taxValueButton.setText(Utils.floatFormater.format(this.taxValue));
        setting.setConfigTax(this.taxValue, this);
        setResult();
      }
    }
  }

  protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    Utils.l("on creat");
    setContentView(2130903040);
    this.context = this;
    setView();
    this.mStatusChecker = new DataCollector(this, true);
    checkUpdate();
    int i = setting.getOpenRecommendStat(this);
    if ((i != 2) && (i != 4) && (i == 5))
      showFeaturedDialog();
    setting.setOpenRecommedTime(this, i + 1);
    this.listTax = new ArrayList();
    this.listPrice = new ArrayList();
    this.listOriginPrice = new ArrayList();
    this.listSaved = new ArrayList();
    this.listDiscount = new ArrayList();
  }

  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu paramMenu)
  {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(paramMenu);
    paramMenu.add(2, 1, 5, getString(2131034131)).setIcon(17301568);
    paramMenu.add(2, 2, 1, getString(2131034130)).setIcon(17301566);
    paramMenu.add(4, 3, 6, getString(2131034129)).setIcon(17301569);
    paramMenu.add(2, 5, 0, getString(2131034133)).setIcon(17301577);
    paramMenu.add(3, 6, 4, getString(2131034153)).setIcon(17301586);
    paramMenu.add(3, 7, 3, getString(2131034158)).setIcon(17301576);
    paramMenu.add(1, 8, 2, getString(2131034164)).setIcon(17301619);
    return true;
  }

  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem paramMenuItem)
  {
    switch (paramMenuItem.getItemId())
    {
    case 1:
      new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(2131034131).setMessage(2131034138).setPositiveButton(2131034118, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
      {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt)
        {
        }
      }).setNegativeButton(2131034134, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
      {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt)
        {
          Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
          localIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.SUBJECT", Calculator.this.getString(2131034136));
          localIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", Calculator.this.getString(2131034137) + "http://market.android.com/search?q=pname:" + Calculator.this.getPackageName());
          localIntent.setType("text/plain");
          Calculator.this.startActivity(localIntent);
        }
      }).show();
      break;
    case 2:
      Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SENDTO");
      localIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:mars@infolife.mobi"));
      localIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.SUBJECT", getString(2131034112) + " Feedback");
      startActivity(localIntent);
      break;
    case 3:
      new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(2131034129).setMessage(2131034135).setPositiveButton(2131034118, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
      {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt)
        {
        }
      }).show();
      break;
    case 5:
      startActivity(new Intent(this, setting.class));
      break;
    case 6:
      startActivity(new Intent(this, FeaturedAppsActivity.class));
      break;
    case 7:
      showDonateDialog();
      break;

    case 4:
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(paramMenuItem);
  }

  public void onPause()
  {
    super.onPause();
    Utils.l("on pause");
    Data.onPause(this);
  }

  public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar paramSeekBar, int paramInt, boolean paramBoolean)
  {
    if (paramSeekBar.getId() == 2131165188)
    {
      this.percentText.setText("  " + paramInt + "% OFF");
      this.percentValue = paramInt;
    }
    setResult();
  }

  public void onResume()
  {
    super.onResume();
    Utils.l("on resume");
    Data.onResume(this);
    setButtonText();
  }

  public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar paramSeekBar)
  {
  }

  public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar paramSeekBar)
  {
  }

  void setAnimation()
  {
    View localView = findViewById(2131165184);
    TranslateAnimation localTranslateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(localView.getWidth(), 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
    localTranslateAnimation.setDuration(1200L);
    localTranslateAnimation.setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(this, 17432586));
    localTranslateAnimation.setStartOffset(200L);
    localView.startAnimation(localTranslateAnimation);
  }

  void setButtonText()
  {
    this.firstButton.setText("-" + setting.getButton1(this) + "%");
    this.secondButton.setText("-" + setting.getButton2(this) + "%");
    this.thirdButton.setText("+" + setting.getButton3(this) + "%");
    this.forthButton.setText("+" + setting.getButton4(this) + "%");
  }

  void setResult()
  {
    boolean bool = false;
    this.resultValue = (this.totalValue * (100 - this.percentValue) / 100.0F);
    this.savedValue = (this.totalValue - this.resultValue);
    if (this.taxBox.isChecked())
    {
      bool = true;
      this.taxValue = Float.parseFloat(this.taxValueButton.getText().toString());
      this.resultValue += this.resultValue * this.taxValue / 100.0F;
      this.savedValue += this.totalValue * this.taxValue / 100.0F * this.percentValue / 100.0F;
    }
    setting.setTaxStat(Boolean.valueOf(bool), this.context);
    this.savedText.setText(getString(2131034124) + " " + Utils.currencyFormater.format(this.savedValue));
    this.resultText.setText(Utils.currencyFormater.format(this.resultValue));
  }

  void setView()
  {
    this.totalPriceLayout = ((LinearLayout)findViewById(2131165209));
    this.totalSavedLayout = ((LinearLayout)findViewById(2131165207));
    this.percentSeekBar = ((SeekBar)findViewById(2131165188));
    this.percentText = ((TextView)findViewById(2131165187));
    this.resultText = ((TextView)findViewById(2131165184));
    this.savedText = ((TextView)findViewById(2131165185));
    this.totalPriceText = ((TextView)findViewById(2131165210));
    this.totalSavedText = ((TextView)findViewById(2131165208));
    this.taxBox = ((CheckBox)findViewById(2131165200));
    this.totalValueButton = ((Button)findViewById(2131165186));
    this.taxValueButton = ((Button)findViewById(2131165201));
    this.firstButton = ((Button)findViewById(2131165189));
    this.secondButton = ((Button)findViewById(2131165190));
    this.thirdButton = ((Button)findViewById(2131165191));
    this.forthButton = ((Button)findViewById(2131165192));
    this.priceList = ((ListView)findViewById(2131165206));
    this.clearButton = ((Button)findViewById(2131165203));
    this.calculateButton = ((Button)findViewById(2131165202));
    this.addButton = ((ImageButton)findViewById(2131165204));
    this.resultText.setFocusable(true);
    this.resultText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    this.totalValueButton.setFocusable(true);
    this.taxBox.setChecked(setting.getTaxStat(this.context));
    this.taxBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this.boxListener);
    this.taxValueButton.setText(String.valueOf(setting.getConfigTax(this)));
    this.taxBox.setText(2131034122);
    this.percentSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    this.firstButton.setOnClickListener(this.buttonListener);
    this.secondButton.setOnClickListener(this.buttonListener);
    this.thirdButton.setOnClickListener(this.buttonListener);
    this.forthButton.setOnClickListener(this.buttonListener);
    this.totalValueButton.setOnClickListener(this.buttonListener);
    this.taxValueButton.setOnClickListener(this.buttonListener);
    this.clearButton.setOnClickListener(this.buttonListener);
    this.calculateButton.setOnClickListener(this.buttonListener);
    if (this.addButton != null)
      this.addButton.setOnClickListener(this.buttonListener);
    setButtonText();
  }
  }
```

I have an error at the end of the block

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete 
     ClassBody
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete 
     FieldDeclaration
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete 
     FieldDeclaration
```

Any ideas how to resolve this please? i've been looking and didn't found anything.

Thank you.

Comment: Kaediil makes a very good point. R.id.name is much simpler and will cause much less problems.  If that does not fix the problem, if you can post more of the code in your program, it would be helpful.

Comment: The entire code is there now.

Comment: First of all, I advice you to indent your code because it's much easier to know what's failling. I think you might have a problem at the `private InfolifeEventListener infolifeEventListener = new InfolifeEventListener()
  {`. Where is the **}** of that listener? Close the listener and all be fine, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, why are you using the hardcoded numbers in the findViewById?  You need to be using R.id.buttonName or something or else those will constantly be getting messed up.  That you need to change almost immediately or you will have no end of trouble going forward.

Comment: Agreed. To add to this answer, there should be a `{` following `if (this.addButton != null)`.

Comment: i can't change the hardcoded numbers now.. it's too late,my entire code is 555 lines so..

Comment: Better to change 555 lines now than 556+ lines later.

Answer (score 1):

Add **;** after your last **}** , and add **}** in a new line at the bottom.
This should solve your error

Comment: bizarre, I tried and this fix syntax error in your code at home.

Comment: but it fixes the errors in the first post, the rest 49 is not highlighted because is not been analyzed before. your code is similar to the code after decompilation by dex2jar

Comment: Agree with silentnuke. This code comes from a decompile by dex2jar.